# QCustomPlot colorMap; scale not updating for new data set

Tags: qt, opencv, colormap, qcustomplot

I have a qCustomPlot colorMap, created in this way:

```
void MainWindow::plot_color_map(QCustomPlot *customPlot, cv::Mat image)
cv::Mat rotated_matrix = cv::Mat(image.rows,image.cols,CV_64FC3);

rotated_matrix.release();   
rotate_90n(image,rotated_matrix,90);

customPlot->clearGraphs();
customPlot->clearPlottables();

customPlot->axisRect()->setupFullAxesBox(true);
customPlot->xAxis->setLabel("x");
customPlot->yAxis->setLabel("y");
customPlot->xAxis->setScaleRatio(customPlot->yAxis,1.0);

QCPColorMap *colorMap = new QCPColorMap(customPlot->xAxis,customPlot->yAxis);
customPlot->addPlottable(colorMap);

colorMap->data()->setSize(rotated_matrix.rows,rotated_matrix.cols); 
colorMap->data()->setRange(QCPRange(0,rotated_matrix.cols),QCPRange(0,rotated_matrix.rows)); 

for(int col = 0; col < rotated_matrix.cols; ++col) {
    for(int row = 0; row < rotated_matrix.rows; row++) {
        colorMap->data()->setCell(row,col,rotated_matrix.at<double>(row,col));
    }
}

QCPColorScale *colorScale = new QCPColorScale(customPlot);

double min,max;
cv::minMaxLoc(rotated_matrix,&min,&max);
qDebug() << min << " " << max;
customPlot->plotLayout()->addElement(0,1,colorScale);
colorScale->setType(QCPAxis::atRight);
colorMap->setColorScale(colorScale); 
colorMap->setGradient(QCPColorGradient::gpJet);

colorMap->rescaleDataRange();

QCPMarginGroup *marginGroup = new QCPMarginGroup(customPlot);
customPlot->axisRect()->setMarginGroup(QCP::msBottom | QCP::msTop, marginGroup);
colorScale->setMarginGroup(QCP::msBottom | QCP::msTop, marginGroup);

customPlot->rescaleAxes();
customPlot->replot();
```

The colorMap is displayed nicely and the scale range matches the "min" and "max" values that I output to the console.

However if I then change the data in the cv::Mat image, the scale does not get updated.

e.g if at first the data range is 0.2 to 7.3, no matter what data I choose to plot after that, the scale is stuck at 0.2 to 7.3, it does not change to reflect the new data set.

Any ideas how to get the scale to auto update to match the data range?

If I close and re-open the program, the first time the function is run, the scale is always correct, only after another image is plotted does it not change.

Thanks 
Mitch

Comment: What do you do after changing `cv::Mat`?

Comment: The whole function is called again with a new cv::Mat containing a different image